# Jquery .hide() not working on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am developing a responsive quiz app, there I am loading all questions on page load, but displaying one question at a time. The UI looks something like this:

[image]

In mobile view, all questions are displayed in a long scroll fashion.

These questions are loaded on the same page after the user clicks a button. That I am doing using `ng-if` and `ng-click` (`AngularJS`)

Now since the content is not present on page load, I have used jquery `.on()` function for previous and next button clicks.

For loading the questions and displaying them I have written a `jquery` function `initialize()`, which displays the questions based on window size. I have called the function both on btn click and window resize.
The function code is:

```
function initialize() {
        alert('called')
        current = 1;
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            var i = 2;
            var next = $("#"+i).length;

            //hide all except first question
            $("#1").show(); //shows first ques
            $("#previous").children('img').addClass('disabled');
            $("#next").children('img').removeClass('disabled');
            while(next>0){ //hides all ques except first
                $("#"+i).hide();
                i++;
                next = $("#"+i).length;
            }
        }
        else{
            //alert('mobile');
            var i = 1;
            var next = $("#"+i).length;

            //show all questions (long scroll)
            while(next>0){
                $("#"+i).show();
                i++;
                next = $("#"+i).length;
            }
        }
```

I have put that `alert()` to check when the function is getting called.
I get the `alert()` , but the `.hide()` does not seems to be working, because all questions are being displayed.

However, when I resize the window, at that time when the function is getting called, everything is working as expected (one ques at a time), `.hide()` is also working.

I am not sure what's wrong. I am stuck on this from 2 days.

Comment: please create fiddle for this functionality if possible

Comment: there's lots of html code, and angular code that's why I can't. @JayeshChitroda

Comment: use `on` or `live` method... it will sort it out.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot How to use .on() with .hide() ? I tried: `$('body').on('hide', '#'+i);`

Comment: @Nivedita after reading your question, I myself experimented the hide() on dynamic divs.. and its working well with me...

Comment: @TirthrajBarot Then why is it not working in my case? Is their any other problem?

Comment: I don't know... can you put some html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116175/discussion-between-nivedita-and-tirthraj-barot).

Comment: have a look at the chat @Nivedita